# Reverse twenty questions

Tags: neural-networks

So given a typology, we can spontaneously generate a series of dichotomies that identifies types. That's what the game twenty questions does. It creates twenty dichotomies based on a neural net it has stored and the player's answers tell it which object to identify.

But what about reverse twenty questions? Given K (where K is very large) n-tuples of "yes or no" questions regarding some kind of objects, is it possible to have a neural network analyze the frequency distribution of these n-tuples to come up with a non-arbitrary categorization schema?

Let me give an example. Suppose I have K points on a map of the Earth. K is very large. For each point, there's an n-tuple of yes or no questions like "can you farm here," "are there four seasons," etc.... From these K n-tuples and looking at their distribution, can an algorithm recreate the Köppen–Geiger climate classification?

Comment: I don't know about neural nets, but you should look into [formal concept analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384031/how-to-compare-different-clusterings/384075#384075)

Comment: Isn't what you describe as reverse K what neural nets do in plain vanilla problems? Just classification. But of course, if it bases it's decision on a certain schema like "Köppen-Geiger" strongly depends on your data. So if it is provided the data required to form this kind of abstraction and second if there are other attributes, that might "distract" the neural net and might lead that it bases it's decisions on other attributes (maybe leading to overfitting or wrong decisions on other sets than the training set).