# Compare two curriculums?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, references

A number of different courses at our institution teach the same skill. We're looking at developing an overall curriculum for everyone to use while teaching this skill, and would like to compare it to each of the existing curriculums followed.

My idea is to have a number of different assessors (ideally one from each discipline) go through the proposed curriculum and the existing curriculums. They'll then be asked whether each item in the proposed curriculum is represented in the existing curriculum they are comparing it to, and give a similarity score for each item on a scale (probably 1-5). This will be repeated by each assessor for several (possibly all) the existing curriculums.

While I'm fairly happy I could then compute inter-assessor variability, I'm a little unclear of which statistic would be best to compare how similar the proposed curriculum is to each existing one.

My background is solely in more basic regression and correlation so I'm rather stuck as to what to use. Google and reddit/ stack exchange searches haven't turned up much in the way that could help, possibly because I imagine this is a fairly unique way of looking at this problem.

Could anyone recommend a statistic to use, or even better a paper or textbook chapter that I can use to get an overview?

Comment: Are the curriculums extensive? This might be a case for trying [Formal concept analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_concept_analysis) , but that might be a large project ... (I have no experience with such ideas, so just an idea) see also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384031/how-to-compare-different-clusterings.  [USING FORMAL CONCEPT ANALYSIS IN EDUCATION](https://www.uni-miskolc.hu/~microcad/publikaciok/2017/c2/C2_6_Korei_Attila.pdf)